# Can't find event definitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this function in my codebase:

```
let touch = true;

function init() {
    let firstMousemoveHasOccured = false;
    $(window).on('mousemove.touchdetection', () => {
        if (firstMousemoveHasOccured) {
            touch = false;
            $(window).off('mousemove.touchdetection touchend.touchdetection');
        } else {
            firstMousemoveHasOccured = true;
        }
    });
    $(window).on('touchend.touchdetection', () => {
        touch = true;
        $(window).off('mousemove.touchdetection touchend.touchdetection');
    });
}
```

The event `mousemove.touchdetection` is not a standard event, so where is this coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [jQuery namespaced events](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

The first part of the event name `mousemove` is the event that, when fired calls the callback. The second part `touchdetection` is meaningless, except it allows you a mechanism to turn off a specific class or group of `mousemove` events, easily.

```
$(document).off('mousemove'); //turns off all callbacks attached to the `mousemove` event.
$(document).off('mousemove.touchdetection'); //turns of all callbacks attached to the mousemove event that have been attached with the touchdetection namespace
```

The purpose of this, as you'll see from reading the API docs is to allow you to easily modify your listeners in your application without affecting listeners attached by third party code.